# How does this return a reference?

Tags: c++, reference

I've been trying to learn how to use a singleton design pattern and stumbled across this:

```
    static S& getInstance()
    {
        static S instance;
        return instance;
    }
```

I noticed here that it returns `instance`, shouldn't it be supposed to return an `instance&`?

Edit: I should also mention that the compiler doesn't seem to be making any complaints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's correct as written. The compiler will create and return a reference to `instance` from the function `getInstance`.

You ask whether it should be `instance&`. First of all, that is not syntactically valid. What about `&instance` then? That would take the address of `instance` and would, therefore, return an `instance *`.

The multiple uses of the `&` operator are a common source of confusion. Here's a quick "cheat-sheet" that doesn't use complex terminology from the standard:

The binary (two argument) version of `&` is applied against two instances of variables and represents bitwise AND (except when overloaded).

```
unsigned int a = 7;
unsigned int b = 3;
unsigned int c = a & b; // c = 3
```

The unary (one argument) version of `&` when applied to a type denotes a reference to a type. Example:

```
int a = 7;
int& ref_a = a; // ref_a is a reference to a
```

The unary (one argument) version of `&` when applied to a variable denotes the `address-of` operator and yields a pointer to the variable.

```
int a = 7;
int* ptr_a = &a;
```

Answer (score 7):

`return instance;` does return a reference to `instance`. That is just like

```
int& r = a;
```

for some `int a` creates a reference to `a` without needing to write `a&` or something like this.